# Create skeleton from commandline

Tags: java, maven, playn

I am following the steps in the [Getting Started Guide](https://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Generating_a_skeleton_project_with_Maven) and am getting a [MissingProjectException](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException) error from Maven (missing pom.xml file).

I have downloaded and installed the JavaSE jdk and Maven. I successfully compiled and ran the PlayN demo showcase for both desktop and html5. I tinkered with the demo "hello" app.

**Now I want to create my own little game starting from a standard PlayN project skeleton. How do I do that from the commandline?** (Win7, Java 1.8, Maven 3.2.1)

I am returning to Java after a decade and have no experience with Maven so I do not know if the guide has unstated prerequisites like copying a default pom.xml file from someplace.

```
(following successful compilation of playn demo showcase in playn-samples)...
PS C:\dev\playn-samples> cd ..
PS C:\dev>
PS C:\dev> mkdir mygame


Directory: C:\dev


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         6/14/2014   5:41 PM            mygame


PS C:\dev> cd .\mygame
```

Paste in the command as per the Getting Started Guide "Generating a skeleton project"...

```
PS C:\dev\mygame> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.276 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-14T17:41:37+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\dev\mygame). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
PS C:\dev\mygame>
```

My Java install...

```
PS C:\dev\mygame> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_05
```

My Maven install...

```
PS C:\dev\mygame> mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-15T02:37:52+09:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
PS C:\dev\mygame>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an issue using PowerShell. Try running this using normal the cmd executable.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb now. Between Powershell and Cygwin, it's been so long since I've used CMD it didn't even occur to me to try it. ... Thank you, that seems to have worked.